# How to extract an element from a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given for example $B=\{A\}$, how do you express $A$ in formal set theory? You'd be tempted to say "the unique element $X$ such that $X$ is a member of $B$", but the only way I know to express "such that" in set theory is with set builder notation:

$$\{X | X \in B\}$$

But this is useless since we've wrapped $A$ up inside a set once again.

This strikes me as an important question, since otherwise how can we express $f(x)$? You'd need something like "the second member of the ordered pair in $f$ whose first member is $x$", which is a more complicated version of the above problem.

Comment: Well, $A = \bigcup B$, but that's a truly ugly hack that only works in pure set theory...

Comment: In the usual axiomatic set theory, it cannot be done. So what one does is to use a $\varphi(x)$ that says what you did, that $x\in B$. **Terms** $t$ of the type you are looking for are used, but formally only as abbreviations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I don't agree with that. I'm allowed to conservatively extend my theory, and you can't stop me! On a more serious note, we'd like to prove that our conservative extensions really are conservative, so a good metatheory is needed. Of course, you'll want to conservatively extend *metatheory* too, so at some point its probably best to say: "You know what? Asserting new definitions in this format is a staple of mathematics. So at my highest-level metatheory, I'm just going to take it as given that these extensions are conservative, for purposes of readability."

Comment: I would sort of agree, except about the need for theory. As long as it is clear to people in the field that in principle we can write something as a sentence in the language of ZF, there is no need of theory.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, you know what, I think you're probably right.

Comment: If you were to treat $\{\bullet\}$ as some kind of container, then another approach is to always keep the top-most container while discarding those inside, e.g. if $B = \{\{A\}\}$, then $\{A\} = \{X \mid \exists Y.\ X \in Y \land Y \in B\}$. Of course, there is a natural mapping from functions that work on $A$ to functions that work on $\{A\}$.

Comment: @dtldarek Your comment seems to give the same construction as Zhen Lin's comment.  It works fine *provided* the element you're trying to extract from a one-element set is itself a set.  That's why Zhen Lin pointed out that it "only works in pure set theory", where everything is a set.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Not exactly, my intention was that you could package every object of your theory into a singleton (i.e. work with $\{A\}$, not $A$), in other words, you might not be able to remove all the braces, but while keeping the top-most "container", you can skip the others.

Comment: It should also probably be noted that this isn't necessary as far as I can see. If for instance you need to check equality, you can just do $\{A\}=\{B\}$.

Comment: @JackM, what if you want to check cardinality?

Comment: You can express $f(x)$ if you don't mind wrapping $f(x)$ up in a new set as $\{f(x)|x\in B\}$ :D

Comment: The rule of inference that lets you get a symbol for an element of a nonempty set is called "existential instantiation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen people write $\iota x Px$ to denote the unique $x$ satisfying $Px$.

However, I don't think its the best way of doing things. I'd much rather write:

> Therefore, there exists a unique $x$ such that $Px$. Thus, let us adjoin a new constant symbol $c$ together with the assumption that $Pc$.

To make proper sense of the above paragraph, you should probably have a read of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension) and [this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/1998-October/002306.html).

Indeed, we can pull essentially same trick for functions.

> Therefore, we have that for all $x$, there exists a unique $y$ such that $Pxy$. Thus, let us adjoin a new function symbol $f(*)$ together with the assumption that $\forall xy[f(x)=y \leftrightarrow Pxy].$

With regards to the "functions as particular kinds of sets" idea found in ZFC, we can define this as follows.

> Therefore, we have that for all functions $f$ with domain $X$, and all $x \in X$, that there exists a unique $y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$. Thus, let us adjoin a new function symbol $* \diamond *$ together with the following sentence.
>
> For all $x$, $X$ and $f$, supposing $f$ has domain $X$ and that $x \in X$, then $f \diamond x = y \leftrightarrow (x,y) \in f.$
>
> Indeed, we will write $f(x)$ rather than $f \diamond x$ whenever there is no scope for confusion.

Now if you're very switched on, you'll be wondering: "But hand on. My axiom schemata (like separation/replacement in ZFC, or first-order induction in PA) have an instance for each formula in my language. But, now that I've extended my language, what guarantee do I have that the schemata apply to the enlarged language?

But perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can fill you in on that issue.

Comment: What needs to be filled in is closely related to what you wrote, in a comment under the question, about making sure this extension is conservative. What's actually needed is a little stronger than conservativity, namely the following: Every formula in the new language (where the newly defined symbol is available) can be translated back into the original language and can be proved (in the enlarged theory) to be equivalent to the translation. Furhtermore, a statement can be proved in the enlarged theory iff its translation can be proved in the original theory.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks for the info. I'm not really sure about the technical details, so feel free to edit this as-of-now community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also thought of it. I call things like $f(x)$ a pseudo-object since it's an object + logical constraint. In the case that logical constraint is not satisfied, there is actually no object and the expression is undefined. Even if $f(x)$ may not be defined, all logical expressions containing it are perfectly defined. $y = f(x) \iff ⟨x, y⟩ ∈ f$ and $f$ is a function. It can be also defined in terms of your element extractor pseudoobject: $f(x) = El(f[\{x\}])$. Where $y ∈ El(x) \iff ∃z: (y ∈ z) ∧ (z = El(x))$ and $y = El(x) \iff (y ∈ x) ∧ (∀y') (y' ∈ x) \to (y' = y)$. Another example of construction like this is $X = A \dot∪ B $ meaning that $X$ is disjoint union of $A$ and $B$. Here $A \dot∪ B$ is pseudoobject of $A ∪ B$ + condition that $A ∩ B = ∅$.